# Apache Spark streaming large number of csv text files with header containing important information

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to stream a large number of `csv` files as a source, each contains a header containing important information for classifying rest of the data that follows.

What is the best way to build a streaming solution which will include the header data against each row that follows under apache spark's distributed processing system?

Problem could be that header could be picked up by any of the executors in case the file processing gets split up.

Answer (score 0):

I would decouple the message creation and the message processing, where message means the combination of header and row that you want.

You can use Kafka (https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python for instance) to build such messages, publish them to a topic and suscribe to that topic in your pyspark application to process them